# Cannot get Phone number of last contact

Tags: android, android-contacts, phone-number

Ive been following the tutorials from [this](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/) site to get the phone number of a contact in Android.

The issue I face is that, I cannot seem to get the last contact number. 
For example, if I have 3 contacts saved it shows the numbers of the first 2.

Im posting my code as well if it helps anyone.

```
if(cur.getCount()>0){
        while(cur.moveToNext()){
            String id=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            if(Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)))>0){
                pCur=getContentResolver().
                        query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, 
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID+"=?", 
                                new String[]{id}, null);
                while(pCur.moveToNext()){
                    number.add(pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
                }                   
            }
            pCur.close();
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

============================

**EDIT:** For those interested below is the code that works for me:

```
Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
    while (phones.moveToNext())
    {
      String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
      String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
      Log.i("Details", "Name: "+name+"  Number: "+phoneNumber);

    }
    phones.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
    String selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;
                        + 
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { "1" };                            
    Cursor c =  getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                                        projection, 
                                        selection, 
                                        selectionArgs, null}
if (c.moveToFirst())
{
     do
     {
        Log.d("Test", "Contact: id = " + c.getLong(0) + " name = " + c.getString(1) + " phone = " + c.getString(2));
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This doesnt seem to be working for me. I've tried to use the do-while loop differently but unfortunately my app force closes. Same thing with this too.

Comment: You should be able to get all the contacts whose have phone with the code above.

Comment: Again my app force closes when I use this code. Ive found a suitable solution from else where. Thank you for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try the following code to get all contacts

```
        Cursor c=dbHelper.getAllContact();
        startManagingCursor(c);
        ArrayList<String> columnArray1 = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {          
                columnArray1.add(c.getString(0));
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
```